# Problems in tuning Random Forest Classifier using RandomizedCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to improve the accuracy of Random Forest Classifier using RandomizedCV and GridsearchCV. Whenever I run the script, It gives me the output, but if I run the script again then it doesn't show the same output. For eg: if on the script the first time it displays on my terminal

```
Accuracy for Random Forests without tuning: 0.7545454545454545
Accuracy for Random Forests by Randomized CV: 0.7272727272727273
Accuracy for Random Forests by Gridsearch CV: 0.7363636363636363
```

And if I run the script again then I get a different output.

```
Accuracy for Random Forests without tuning: 0.7636363636363637
Accuracy for Random Forests by Randomized CV: 0.7454545454545455
Accuracy for Random Forests by Gridsearch CV: 0.7454545454545455
```

Here's the code for the same

```
X = df1[['ANSWER', 'TEXT']]  # dependent
y = df1['ID']  # independent

# split dataset in train and test set.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)  # 70% training and 30% test data

# Random Forest Classifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
print('Accuracy for Random Forests without tuning:', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Why is it fluctuating everytime I run the script?

I am also trying to improve its accuracy-just for the RandomizedCV, it gives me the best parameters and if I use those on my model, then rather than improving the accuracy, it decreases the accuracy, ie if the accuracy is 0.7636 and I use the best parameter to improve it then I get the acccuracy as 0.69 or 0.71 something on the similar lines.
Here's the code for RandomizedCV.

```
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in range(200, 2000, 200)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num=11)]
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
bootstrap = [True, False]
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap
               }
print(random_grid)

hyp_rf = RandomForestClassifier()
hyp_rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=hyp_rf, param_distributions=random_grid, n_iter=100, cv=3, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
hyp_rf_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
prophecy = hyp_rf_random.predict(X_test)
print('Tuned Random Forests:', accuracy_score(y_test, prophecy))
print('Best parameters', hyp_rf_random.best_params_)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a random seed for the train/test split, too? Only doing it for the model might not be enough to ensure full reproducibility, and you might simply be evaluating against slightly different sets.

Comment: @dennlinger thanks for your prompt response, I am not sure what you mean by a random seed.. there is something called as random_state which I had set to 42 but they still gave me different outputs.

Comment: In the above function, you do not set a seed in `train_test_split`. This function [also takes a `random_state` as an argument](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). This does not explain quite why your CV version does differ, but maybe resolves the first problem.

Comment: @dennlinger Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, I still get the error.